# Bash Script- Process CSV file

Tags: shell, csv, sed

I have `3rd` field in `CSV` for DateOfBirth as: `02041996`

I want to change its format to `02/04/1996`. Is there any way to add `/` after specific number of digits?

Comment: show an exemplary line. Besides, you have shown `19996`

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo, it is 1996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will split the 3rd using `split` function of `awk` and each field is separated by nothing `""`. Later in print statement, each field is called using `a[N]`.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=,  '{split($3,a,"");$3=a[1]a[2]"/"a[3]a[4]"/"a[5]a[6]a[7]a[8]}1' csvFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ***awk***'s `substr` function:

```
awk -F, '{ $3=substr($3,1,2)"/"substr($3,3,2)"/"substr($3,5) }1' OFS=',' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, '{$3 = gensub(/([^ ]{2})([^ ]{2})(.*)/, "\\1/\\2/\\3", "g", $3)}1' OFS=','
```

Sample:

```
AMD$ echo " col1 ,   col2,    02041996, col4 " | awk -F, '{$3 = gensub(/([^ ]{2})([^ ]{2})(.*)/, "\\1/\\2/\\3", "g", $3)}1' OFS=','
 col1 ,   col2,    02/04/1996, col4
```